# Newbie GM several questions

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm reading the manuals and I have not run a game yet:

1) When there is a Wisdom (Perception or any other thing) check, do I add Wisdom modifier AND perception modifier? (Only if there is proficiency?)

2) The spells that require a material component such as grains of sand or other inexpensive materials: does the PC have to buy it, or is it a resource to interpret the casting?

3) On character creation: I have seen apps that let you add 2 proficiencies of choice, is it correct?

4) Do spell casters know ALL the spells? How do I choose spells on creation? (Or does it depend on the GM?)

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to the site ! You may want to take the tour (http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the format of the questions and answers. You should probably divide your question in multiple ones, it will be easier to answer and find/use for the other users

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to post several questions because they were too short, I'll read it right away

Comment: I edited your question to try and make it smoother to read.  If English is not your first language, please accept my assistance. If what I did makes the meaning wrong, please edit it to make it mean what you want it to mean.  Welcome to RPG.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On the character sheet, the value for each skill is the sum of your ability modifier (let's say +2 Wisdom mod.) and your proficiency bonus (+2 at level 1), **if** you are proficient with this skill. This means that for the Perception skill, you would have +4 if you are proficient in Perception. For a Wisdom (Perception) check, you use the +4 modifier, and don't add the proficiency bonus again.
2. Spells can require components. Some components, like diamonds, will be consumed (there is always a value in gold and the spell specifies it). If the spellcaster owns a spell focus (orb, staff), he/she doesn't need to have the components to cast the spell, **except** if those  will be consumed, OR have a gold value (PHB p. 203). This is why the players almost always have the choice between a component belt pouch or a focus in their starting equipment.
3. Proficiency can be obtained through different methods, like the class or the background. If you gain proficiency in something you already have, you can **freely** choose **any** other one.
4. Some spellcasters gain access to their whole spell lists (for which they have spell slots) when they level up (priest, paladin), others can choose a limited number of spells each level (wizard). For classes like the wizard, the PHB indicates how many spells you start with at level 1.

Comment: @Nemenia we generally discourage (in the form of downvotes) people from answering questions that should be, or are very likely to be, put on hold since it can stop the OP from ever clearing up their question just because they "got an answer". I can't say that that's the reason in this case but it *could* be.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey well hold on, i disagree with this. the question "Can an Unseen Servant be physically touched and manipulated?" contains multiple questions, and it's considered feasible because they're all under the same topic. why is this on hold for being too broad when the other is not? Is it just because the other one involves a single spell rather than general skill information?

Comment: I commented on the question about splitting in multiple ones, but I took the time to answer nevertheless. As a relatively new member, it was sometimes frustrating to get a question closed without any kind of answers, so I wanted to ease the first time asking one for OP.

Comment: @Nemenia Pretty much, yeah. A post can have multiple questions so long as they're tightly focused around the same core concept (within reason and yes, there are boarder-line cases). The *Unseen Servant* questions are, essentially, all focused on one specific thing which is summed up in the title. This question however is asking about multiple *different* things, multiple *different* mechanics. It *should* be split up and asked separately. You'll come to learn the difference is you stick around long enough. Anyway, further discussion should be taken to [chat] should you wish to continue it.

Comment: @Yotus Just a heads up. Whilst it's great that you are trying to help a new user, answering a question when it's really not currently a good sit for the site (for whatever reason) can actually be somewhat harmful. Yes, it can be frustrating to get a question closed without any kind of answers, but the whole point of putting a question on hold is *because* it's not currently a good fit for the site, it needs work. "Problems" need to be addressed. It's less likely that a user is going to learn anything about the site's policies if their question's answered before the problems are addressed.